# d3 single stacked chart with rounded corners only on first and last rect's

Tags: d3.js

I have a stacked chart that i need the corners to be rounded , i tried adding .attr("rx",10) and ry , 10. But that way all rects are getting round, and thats not what i need, the first one needs a left round corner and the last one needs a right round corner.

this is the chart js

```
var datavars = [224, 84, 29];
var colors = ['green','blue','darkgray'];

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', 500)
.attr('height', 100);

svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(datavars)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('width', function(d){
    return d;})
               .attr('x',function(d, i){
               return sum(datavars, 0, i); })
.attr('fill', function(d, i){ return colors[i]; })
.attr('y',0)
.attr('height', 30);


function sum(array, start, end) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i=start; i<end; i++) total += array[i];
  return total;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `selection.filter()` to filter the first and last elements of the selection. But it is not possible to round just some of the corners of a rect - they all have the same value. The alternative would be to use `path` elements instead, and plot out the corners as Bezier curves.